# Did Kobe Bryant jump over a car?

Tags: video

There is a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIWeEFV59d4) that went viral about a sports star, Kobe Bryant, jumping over an Aston Martin. I'm really skeptical that his management would let him attempt that, but is there any evidence about whether the video is authentic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Kobe Bryant said in an interview that it's a fake.

http://sportsbybrooks.com/kobe-explains-car-jump-video-17131

Here's an explanation on how to use after effects to do a similar video (it's quite easy!):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWi-rVy49JE

Answer (score 3):

I'd be inclined to believe the shoe retailers are behind the video. A year ago, [this video of a new sport called Liquid Mountaineering](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oe3St1GgoHQ) went pretty viral as well. A key point in the video is that they found these shoes that are completely water repellant. Kobe seems to attribute quite a lot to the shoes as well. You don't see that with people who are winning the olympics :)

Of course I can't prove that the shoe retailers are behind it, but that doesn't really make a difference. The Liquid Mountaineering video, though well made, was obviously fake, as you simply can't do that. It's not as obvious that you *couldn't* do what Kobe does in that video, but it would certainly be *easier* to fake it. He's probably just standing closer to the camera than the car is, so he's jumping in front of the car (from our perspective). The jump still has to be just as impressive, but it would be completely safe to perform it, and he could try it a hundred times until he got it right.

Comment: When you pause the video at the moment where Kobe lifts off, it does indeed look like he is a little closer to the camera than the car. So there was never any danger of Kobe actually getting hit by the car.